# Is that possible to append the querystring in the controller for MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to append values to the URL in the server side action. Is that possible? Looks like we have to do that from the browser side when submit the request. Is there an generic way to add querystring to the URL?

Comment: ajax? (foosentence to comment)

Comment: Can you explain the scenario a little better?  Where are you getting the querystring?  Why does it have to be a querystring going to the next action?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible ...
 Use JavaScript to append the selected value to the domain before it submits. Change the button to have an onclick attribute as oppose to making it submit the form.

Add this JavaScript to your head section (or wherever you want, but convention is typically the HEAD section or bottom of the body)

Comment: The question was from the server side. I don't this js in the <head> will do.